# Why does the Perseverance landing site have three close bright dots in a line, with a perpendicular dark streak?

Tags: mars, perseverance

The [February 27 Astronomy Picture of the Day](https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/ap210227.html) has a picture of the Perseverance landing region taken by the Mars Reconnaissance Orbiter. The landing site itself has a distinctive look:

[image: Perseverance landing site] [image: Closer landing site view]

The left image is from the APOD page, and the right is from [this NASA page](https://photojournal.jpl.nasa.gov/catalog/PIA24334). From the right image, it is clear that the dot in the middle is the rover itself, and the light patches to the upper right and lower left are probably where the rockets scoured away an upper darker level of soil. But what is the dark streak? And why are there two separate patches? With four rockets in a boxy rectangle 25 feet up, I would have expected a single oval scoured patch.

Comment: This are most likely the result of the skycrane rocket blast pushing the darker dirt together between them, but I have no documented source for that.

Comment: @GdD I am sure you are right, see [comment](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/50424/#comment164209_50426). These (PIA24334) are cropped from [PIA24333](https://photojournal.jpl.nasa.gov/catalog/PIA24333) and this is from the monochrome Context Camera (CTX) not HiRise. [CTX](http://www.msss.com/all_projects/mro-ctx.php) covers [500 to 800nm](http://www.msss.com/science/mro-ctx-instrument-description.php) from green to near infrared, and so images will respond differently to the quantity and arrangement of fine martian dust particles than an image from HiRise would.

Answer (score 2):

The landing system jets are angled off to either side of the rover, resulting in the surface disturbance pattern you noticed.

[image]

From [Mars Science Laboratory: Entry, Descent, and Landing System Performance](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/20090007730/downloads/20090007730.pdf), I added the red arrows.

This picture from [Popular Science](https://www.popsci.com/technology/article/2011-04/video-new-mars-rover-will-land-using-sky-crane-solar-system-first/) shows a more orthogonal view with the plumes from all 4 jets.

[image]

Comment: is it possible to address why the side lobes are *brighter* than average while at the same time the central strip which is parallel to the "fly off" direction is *darker* than average? I think that's the thrust of the question (pun intended). I think that [this comment](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/50424/#comment164203_50424) is on the right track; the central streak is a "piled higher and deeper" collection of regolith removed from the two side lobes; if less=brighter then more=darker. If it's removed from one place it has to end up somewhere else. But hmm... how to support...

Comment: Unfortunately the papers I read only showed the surface impingement patterns from a single jet.

Comment: See Figure 11 and caption, and also the last paragraph of section 2.9.1 (paragraph [54]) of [Context Camera Investigation on board the Mars Reconnaissance Orbiter](https://agupubs.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1029/2006JE002808) I think it can be sufficient. Noted [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/50424/#comment164213_50424) that this is the Context Camera (CTX) and not HiRise.

Comment: It looks from the landing video as if the rockets are in two parallel pairs, two angling down and to the rover's left, and the other two angling down and to the rover's right. I think this is what you mean to convey, but it can't be unambiguously inferred from the diagram, which only shows the view from one angle.

Comment: @uhoh I looked at that paper and it's over my head to  see what Figure 11 has to do with this question.  But IANA geologist. I was looking for a prediction of the plume/surface interaction for the pattern of all 4 jets.

Comment: @MarkFoskey added a picture showing all 4 jets.

Comment: @OrganicMarble I'm thinking that in the OP's photos the dark centerline between the two cleared spots is likely dark because it contains piled up regolith removed from the two white spots. Figure 11 also shows that in a CTX image regolith removed from an area and redeposited nearby is darker. This part: "The distribution of the dark rays, an indicator of the surface dust disruption, is asymmetric, implying that the impactor came in from the south‐southeast. While quite young..." seems to apply.

Comment: @OrganicMarble I'm not saying it's a slam-dunk nor that it rises to the level of an answer but it may help at some point. OP asks about three bright spots; two are likely cleared areas, the third is likely the reflective rover. OP also asks about the "dark streak" and that's where this may be helpful; if you have cleared areas, then you must also have redeposited areas, and the paper shows that a redeposited area from a "young area" can look dark in the CTX camera.

Comment: @uhoh thanks, I understand now.  I'm gonna continue my quest for the plume/surface interaction graphic.